# The background becomes black when I add DaisyUI in my SvelteJS+Tailwindcss Project

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit, daisyui

I was configuring with my SvelteJS and Tailwindcss project with DaisyUI. But every time I add DaisyUI to a Project the background color becomes black. Maybe it's a default color that's not the problem. but how will I change it?
After a lot of searches, I found if I add `data-theme="corporate"` default HTML tag it's gone. But I don't think it's a good idea to change the default HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-theme="corporate">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <link rel="icon" href="%svelte.assets%/favicon.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        %svelte.head%
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>%svelte.body%</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please show me the correct way to change these colors in DaisyUI?

Answer (score 3):

Based on https://github.com/saadeghi/daisyui/issues/338

Try changing to `base:false` in your daisyUI config.

https://daisyui.com/docs/config/

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue while using chrome in dark mode.

This is what worked for me:

```
 #tailwind.config.js

 daisyui: {
  darkTheme: "light",
 },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I solved it by customizing the dark theme, which is the default theme if you're using the browser in dark mode. The base-100 color seems to be responsible for the background color. I changed it to my desired color for the background and it worked.

`daisyui: { styled: true, themes: [ { dark: { ...require("daisyui/src/colors/themes")["[data-theme=dark]"], "base-100": "#15122D", // your desired bg-color }, }, ], };`

Alternatively, as the other answer here suggests to set base:false is a better solution.